# Curvature invariant under isometry but not parallel transport?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, symmetric-spaces

I have read that the curvature is invariant under isometry in the general, though I'm urrently reading up a little on symmetric spaces and I've seen that we have

$\nabla R=0$ iff the space is locally symmetric.

But isn't this condition just the statement that curvature is invarient under parallel transport, which is an isometry?

I'm guessing that not all spaces are locally symmetric, but can't seem to figure out where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: Parallel transport is an isometry between two tangent spaces. It is not an isometry of the manifold!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is true is that if $f : M \to M$ is an isometry, , $f^*g = g$, and then $f^*\nabla = \nabla$ and consequently this leads to $f^*R = R$. So an isometry of $M$ leaves unvariant the curvature.

But this has nothing to do with parallel transport: say $\gamma : I \to M$ is a smooth path and let $P_t$ be the parallel transport from $\gamma(0)$ to $\gamma(t)$. Then:
$$
P_t : \left(T_{\gamma(0)}M,g_{\gamma(0)}\right) \to \left(T_{\gamma(t)}M,g_{\gamma(t)}\right) $$
is a linear isometry. It is not an isometry of $M$.

In fact, on a connected riemannian manifold, any two points can be joined by a smooth path and thus, there are always parallel transport between them. But they may not even exist an isometry of $M$ sending one point to another given one in the general case. This would imply that $M$ is two-point homogeneous and this has huge consequences on the curvature.

Comment: Thanks, all the similar terminology definitely gets confusing. The comment about homogenous space makes it a bit easier to understand the difference between locally and globally symmetric too. Would it be right to say that these vector space isometries between the

Comment: Sorry, would it be right to say these vector space isometries imply the existance of local isometries in a normal ball?

Comment: No, this is false. This would imply the same kind of consequences on curvature

Comment: So is there any implication between vector space isometries and manifold isometries, or is the similar naming convention just down to the fact that they both affect metrics?

Comment: Any isometry $f$ induces linear isometries $df(x) : T_xM \to T_{f(x)}M$ between tangent spaces.

Comment: Is there anything that can be said in the other direction?

Comment: In general, one cannot "integrate" a linear isometry between two tangent spaces into a (local) isometry of $M$, so the answer is no.

Comment: Sorry to keep adding questions, but would the ability to integrate over these linear isometries be given by the usual frobenius integrability conditions in the isometry group of the manifold? So that if the linear subspaces generated by our linear isometries could then form an integral submanifold of the isometry group, that this submanifold would consist of isometries on our base manifold?